# How to create XSD with constrains base on the value of attribute?

Tags: xml, xsd

I am new to XSD, and have difficulty to create a XSD to validate the following incoming XML message.

The difficulty I have are:

1. The data elements "Field", whose attribute "position" value equal to "FirstName" or "LastName" must exist, and only appear once.
2. The data element "Field", whose attribute "position" value equal to "MiddleName" is optional. And if it appears, it can only appears once.
3. Date Element "Fields" will only have those three sub elements, or two if the "MiddleName" one is not exist.

Any idea to do it?

---

Incoming original XML, which need the XSD to validate.

```
<Message>  
  <MessageTypeIndicator version="1" class="8" function="2" origin="3"/>
  <Fields>
     <Field position="FirstName">Jason</Field>
     <Field position="LastName">Smith</Field>
     <Field position="MiddleName">dk</Field>
  </Fields>
</Message>
```

---

Later on, I will also create a XSLT to translate the original XML to something like:

```
<Person>
    <MessageTypeIndicator>
        <version>1</version>
        <class>8</class>
        <function>2</function>
        <origin>3</origin>
    </MessageTypeIndicator>
    <FirstName>Jason</FirstName>
    <LastName>Smith</LastName>
    <MiddleName>dk</MiddleName>
</Person>
```

---

the following is xslt I created so far without validation

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

    <xsl:stylesheet>
      <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
      <xsl:template match="/">
        <Message>      
          <MessageTypeIndicator>        
              <version>
                <xsl:value-of select="Message/MessageTypeIndicator/@version"/>
              </version>      
              <class>
                <xsl:value-of select="Message/MessageTypeIndicator/@class"/>            
              </class>      
              <function>
                <xsl:value-of select="Message/MessageTypeIndicator/@function"/>            
              </function>       
              <origin>
                <xsl:value-of select="Message/MessageTypeIndicator/@origin"/>            
              </origin>    
          </MessageTypeIndicator>
          <xsl:for-each select="Message/Fields/Field">
            <xsl:if test="@position='FirstName'">
              <FirstName>
              <xsl:value-of select="string(.)"/>
            </FirstName>
            </xsl:if>      
            <xsl:if test="@position='LastName'">
            <LastName>
              <xsl:value-of select="string(.)"/>
            </LastName>
            </xsl:if>      
            <xsl:if test="@position='MiddleName'">
            <MiddleName>
              <xsl:value-of select="string(.)"/>
            </MiddleName>
            </xsl:if>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </Message>
      </xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot really use XSD 1.0 to do this kind of checking - it is possible to check if attributes or elements are present or not, but not if an element is present with specific values of its attribute.

What you can do rather easily is to do the checks in the XSLT though - something like this:

```
<xsl:template match="Message">
  <xsl:if test="count(Fields/Field[@position='FirstName']) != 1">
    <xsl:message terminate="yes">The message must exactly one 'FirstName' field</xsl:message>
  </xsl:if>
  <xsl:if test="count(Fields/Field[@position='MiddleName']) > 1">
    <xsl:message terminate="yes">The message cannot contain multiple 'MiddleName' fields</xsl:message>
  </xsl:if>
  <xsl:if test="count(Fields/Field[@position!='MiddleName']) > 3">
    <xsl:message terminate="yes">Too many fields</xsl:message>
  </xsl:if>
  <Person>
    <MessageTypeIndicator>
      <version>1</version>
      <class>8</class>
      <function>2</function>
      <origin>3</origin>
    </MessageTypeIndicator>
    <FirstName>
      <xsl:value-of select="Fields/Field[@position='FirstName']"/>
    </FirstName>
    <LastName>
      <xsl:value-of select="Fields/Field[@position='LastName']"/>
    </LastName>
    <MiddleName>
      <xsl:value-of select="Fields/Field[@position='MiddleName']"/>
    </MiddleName>
  </Person>
</xsl:template>
```

will do the checks and then the conversion.

Comment: Thank you so much, it's a good idea to do the validation in XSLT.

Answer (score 1):

These kind of validations cant be implemented in XSD 1.0. You should either look into using [XSD 1.1](http://www.xfront.com/xml-schema-1-1/) or using [Schematron](http://www.schematron.com/).

Answer (score 1):

The person who designed this document, by using very abstract element names like Message and Field, and then specializing them with attributes like MessageTypeIndicator and Position, probably thought that they were being clever by designing something flexible and extensible. They weren't; XML is already quite flexible and extensible enough if you use concrete elements like

```
<Person><First>Jason</First><Last>Smith</Last></Person>
```

The extra level of abstraction achieves nothing, other than making the XML harder to process, and one aspect of that is that you can't write a precise schema for it. Perhaps that's actually what the designer had in mind: perhaps they wanted to keep it flexible and extensible and knew that once people started writing schemas, it would lose that flexibility and extensibility that they worked so hard (and fruitlessly) to achieve.

Comment: Thanks for your help and suggestion, but the structure of incoming XML is totally out of my control. It will be sent from our external client. If it's well structured, it probably will only take me few minutes with some tool (e.g. Altova XMLSpy and Mapforce to) finish it

Comment: BTW, the incoming sample xml I put here is much simplified, and I also change the attribute value to more readable to make my issue easy to be understand. The real incoming xml message is built base on a ISO8583 string, which have 128 data elements, most of them are optional. Value of attribute "position" is the index of data element, which is a integer between 1 to 128. <Message>
<MessageTypeIndicator version="0" class="8" function="0" origin="0"/>
<Fields>
<Field position="3">
000000
</Field>
<Field position="11">
000001
</Field>
<Field position="41">
29110001
</Field>
</Fields>
</Message>